# Annoying inability to format things

Tags: support, markdown, formatting

Recently a change has made

```
**Theorem** adsfdf
*proof*: asdfdsaf
```

comes out as

**Theorem** adsfdf
*proof*: asdfdsaf

rather than having a line break between them.

```
**Theorem** adsfdf

*proof*: asdfdsaf
```

comes out as

**Theorem** adsfdf

*proof*: asdfdsaf

which looks ugly.

How to deal with this?

Comment: "which looks ugly." No, that's how theorems and proofs are supposed to look. They're different paragraphs.

Answer (score 9):

I don't there's been any recent change; this is how things have always worked.

[To get a single line break, put two spaces at the end of the line](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) - for example,

```
**Theorem** adsfdf  
*proof*: asdfdsaf
```

produces

**Theorem** adsfdf
*proof*: asdfdsaf

Comment: The proof is circular and assumes the wanted conclusion holds. (1/10 points)